# Multiplication of two impulse function $\delta(t)\cdot \delta(t)=?$

Tags: signal-analysis, impulse-response, dirac-delta-impulse

If a impulse function is mulplied with a function $f(x)$ then the formula will be apply
$$f(x)\delta(x-a)=f(a)\delta(x-a)$$ so from this formula mulplication of two impulse function will be

> $$\delta(t)\delta(t)=\delta(0)\delta(t)$$

But,what if i take two impulse function as the approximation of standard signal (rectangular or gaussian) and mulplied them directy then i will get again an impulse function of same property.

[image]

What is wrong with this two?

Comment: Strictly speaking the function multiplying the generalized function $\delta(t)$ should be a sufficiently smooth continuous one. Otherwise the multiplication is undefined. You can have a look at the generalized function theory and distribution theory books.

Comment: See the mathoverflow question [Is square of Delta function defined somewhere?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48067/is-square-of-delta-function-defined-somewhere)

Answer (score 5):

The property

$$f(t)\delta(t-t_0)=f(t_0)\delta(t-t_0)\tag{1}$$

is only valid for a *function* $f(t)$ that is continuous at $t=t_0$. Since the Dirac delta impulse $\delta(t)$ is not a function (it is a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics))) and since $\delta(t)$ is not continuous, property $(1)$ does not hold (and does not make sense) for $f(t)=\delta(t)$.

The product $\delta(t)\cdot \delta(t)$ is undefined. Also note that the quantity $\delta(0)$ is meaningless. Since $\delta(t)$ is not a function you cannot determine its value for any value of its argument.

Comment: have a look at the original [question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/44041/convolution-of-sin-omega-t-and-cos-omega-t) and **consistent** usage of $\delta(0)$ in its solution. (where $\delta(0)$ is used in both time domain and Fourier domain computation of an improper (divergent) convolution)

Comment: @Fat32: OK, but I still don't think that $\delta(0)$ makes any sense. $\delta(0)=\infty$ may be an intuitive way to think about it, but it is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following (weak) argumentation to deduce that the result is interpreted as the (not very meaningful statement of)
$$ \delta(t) \cdot \delta(t) = \delta(0) \cdot \delta(t) $$

Define the impulse as a limit of the following pulse function

$$ \delta(t) = \lim_{\Delta \to 0} \delta_{\Delta}(t) $$ where $\delta_{\Delta}(t)$ is a rectangular function with the definition that

$$ \delta_{\Delta}(t) = \begin{cases}
0 &,\ t < 0 \\
\frac{1}{\Delta} &,\ 0 \le t < \Delta \\
0 &,\ \Delta \le t
\end{cases} $$

Then you can define the multiplication as:
$$\begin{align}
\delta(t)\delta(t) &= \left(  \lim_{\Delta \to 0}\delta_{\Delta}(t) \right) \left(  \lim_{\sigma \to 0}\delta_{\sigma}(t) \right)\\
&= \lim_{\Delta \to 0} \lim_{\sigma \to 0} \left[ \delta_{\Delta}(t)  \delta_{\sigma}(t) \right]\\
 &= \lim_{\Delta \to 0} \left( \delta_{\Delta}(t)  \lim_{\sigma \to 0}   \delta_{\sigma}(t) \right)\\
\text{now observe that}\\
\delta_{\Delta}(t)  \lim_{\sigma \to 0}   \delta_{\sigma}(t)  &\approx \delta_{\Delta}(0)  \lim_{\sigma \to 0}   \delta_{\sigma}(t) = \delta_{\Delta}(0) \delta(t)
\end{align} $$ where the equality holds in the limit. Then proceed with

$$
\begin{align}
\delta(t)\delta(t) &= \lim_{\Delta \to 0} \left( \delta_{\Delta}(0)    \delta(t) \right) \\
\delta(t)\delta(t) &= \left( \lim_{\Delta \to 0} \delta_{\Delta}(0)    \right) \delta(t) \\
\delta(t)\delta(t) &= \left(  \delta(t)|_{t=0}  \right)  \delta(t) \\
\delta(t)\delta(t) &= \delta(0)   \delta(t) \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: So why is it "not very meaningful"? All the math looks perfectly OK to me.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, does "$\delta(0)$" look perfectly OK?

Comment: and i would like to see anyone successfully convolve these two functions: $$ x(t) = 1 \qquad \forall t \in \mathbb{R} $$ and $$ h(t) = 1 \qquad \forall t \in \mathbb{R} $$

Comment: @DilipSarwate not meaningful in the classical (19th century) mathematical sense... Classical point set topology is fundamentally based on smoothness and density. So that the concept of limit, integral and derivate makes sense. It cannot be used to model a blackhole nor a quark however... More modern mathematics deals with distributions in a more consistent way but I'm not sure of its **justifications**, which however are no less meaningful than the justifications of **smoothness**!

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson The point is that the limit does not exist at $t=0$ (the value of $\delta_{\Delta}(t)$ at $t=0$ is $\frac{1}{\Delta}$ which diverges to $\infty$ as $\Delta \to 0$) and even if the limit exists, we cannot claim that the "value" of $\delta(t)$ at $t=0$ _equals_ this limit without assuming that $\delta(t)$ is continuous at $t=0$. In short, Fat32's "argument" perpetuates the myth that $\delta(t)$ is an ordinary function. That he knows better is shown in his comment above as well as in his comment on the OP's question.

Comment: i think i agree with you @DilipSarwate.  i misunderstood your original comment that seemed to imply that Fat's math "looks perfectly OK".

Comment: @Fat32 "$\delta_{\Delta}(t)  \lim_{\sigma \to 0}   \delta_{\sigma}(t) \approx \delta_{\Delta}(0) $ $\lim_{\sigma \to 0}   \delta_{\sigma}(t) = \delta_{\Delta}(0) \delta(t)$" sir can you explain this, how did you approximate it ?

Comment: @Rohit for sufficiently smooth functions (at the point of impulse) $f(x) \delta_{\Delta}(x-a) \approx f(a) \delta_{\Delta}(x-a)$ is understandable. (since $\delta_{\Delta}(x-a)$ is a proper classic function before the limit taken) in other words, **during the impulse** the continuous function $f(x)$ does (can) not change (much) about its value at $x=a$. Then you can take the **constant** $f(a)$ out of the limit and it becomes $ \approx f(a) \lim_{\Delta \to 0}  \delta_{\Delta}(x-a)$ which becomes exact after the limit as $ f(x)\delta(x-a) = f(a)  \delta(x-a)$

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson done. See the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Well, since

$$\pi^2\delta(0)^2=2\int_0^\infty t dt-\frac1{12}$$
we have
$$\delta(0)^2=\frac2{\pi^2}\int_0^\infty t dt-\frac1{12\pi^2}$$

So, we can write $\delta(x)^2$ as

$$\delta(x)^2=\frac1{\pi^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |t| \cos(xt) dt-\frac{0^{|x|}}{12\pi^2}$$

Comment: This is complete nonsense

Comment: @Jazzmaniac what exactly? This does not work for you?

Comment: Do you actually believe that what you wrote here is proper math? If you do, then there's no point in argueing.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac there is an explanation here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115743/an-algebra-of-integrals/342651#342651

Comment: No, that's not an explanation. It's just more incoherent, hand-waving and inconsistent impressionistic "math". This is very far from a rigorous argument. My comment above still stands.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac if you see some inconsistencies, you are welcome to point them. There are definitely which I know, but the do not touch this result.