# Integral of product of two shifted Dirac impulses

Tags: signal-analysis, continuous-signals, impulse-response, dirac-delta-impulse

[In this question the multiplication of two impulse functions is discussed](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/44080/multiplication-of-two-impulse-function-deltat-cdot-deltat)

However, what if I have two shifted impulses say:

$z(t) = \delta(t-\tau)\cdot \delta(t-\beta)$

Now if I want to integrate $z(t)$ how would I go about it? Let's say the integral is:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-\tau)\cdot \delta(t-\beta) dt $$

Comment: That vanishes for $\beta \neq \tau$ and is undefined otherwise. In general, if you encounter a product of two Dirac distributions with the same variable, you've most likely made a mistake elsewhere. It's not something that should happen.

Comment: I know the result and have an intuitive idea for it. But can it be expressed as a Dirac Delta function?

Comment: @Jazzmaniac: At first I thought exactly the same, but now I think that since convolution of two delta impulses IS well-defined, that integral is actually a convolution and the result should be $\delta(\beta-\tau)$.

Comment: @Matt L. How exactly is it a convolution? If it were shouldn't the integral have been:  $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-\tau)\cdot \delta(t) dt$

Comment: @MattL. it's not defined within the framework of functional analysis. If you want to define it, then you need to make sure it doesn't result in contradictions, which may be difficult since the special case of integrating over $\delta^2$, i.e. $\beta=\tau=0$ cannot be modelled uniquely by a converging sequence of functions. Of course, sometimes it may make sense to handwave these issues away, but I wouldn't trust any result obtained this way.

Comment: @AhsonYousef, maybe you could provide the underlying problem that you are trying to solve and your intuitive solution. Then we can see if there's a better way to spell it out mathematically.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac: Wouldn't you agree that $\delta(t-t_1)*\delta(t-t_2)=\delta(t-(t_1+t_2))$?

Comment: It's not a exactly a problem but something that came up in my signal processing lecture, recently.

Comment: @MattL. that's not the integral of the OP though. If you remove the driving variable of the distributions then they're not meaningful objects anymore in the sense of distribution theory.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac: OK, I'll write up an answer and I'd be grateful if you pointed out my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplication of two Dirac impulses is undefined. However, convolution of two Dirac impulses is defined [1]:

$$\delta(t-t_1)\star\delta(t-t_2)=\delta\big(t-(t_1+t_2)\big)\tag{1}$$

Writing out $(1)$ gives

$$\begin{align}\delta(t-t_1)\star\delta(t-t_2)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x-t_1)\delta(t-x-t_2)dx\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x-t_1)\delta(x-(t-t_2))dx\tag{2}\end{align}$$

where I've used the fact that $\delta(t)$ is even.
The last integral in $(2)$ has the same form as the integral in the OP. Hence, using $(1)$ with $t_1=\tau$ and $t-t_2=\beta$ we obtain

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-\tau)\delta(t-\beta)dt=\delta(\beta-\tau)\tag{3}$$

As correctly pointed out by Jazzmaniac, the integral in $(3)$ is a distribution, and as such it only makes sense if wrapped by an integral with $\beta$ or $\tau$ as the integration variable. This is always the case with Dirac impulses and distributions in general. Eq. $(3)$ has to be understood in that sense.

---

[1] A. Papoulis, *The Fourier Integral and Its Applications*, p. 275

> The quantity $\delta^2(t)$ is undefined, however,
> $$\small{\delta(t-t_1)*\delta(t-t_2)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(\tau-t_1)\delta(t-\tau-t_2)\,d\tau=\delta[t-(t_1+t_2)]\tag{I-29}}$$
> as we can easily see from $\text{(I-15)}$.

---

> The product of two distributions $g_1(t)$ and $g_2(t)$ is, in general, undefined; however, their convolution is given by
> $$\small{\begin{array}{rl}\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty\bigg[\int_{-\infty}^\infty g_1(\tau)g_2(t-\tau)\,d\tau&\hspace{-1em}\bigg]\phi(t)\,dt\\&\displaystyle\hspace{-1em}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g_1(\tau)\bigg[\int_{-\infty}^\infty g_2(t-\tau)\phi(t)\,dt\bigg]d\tau\tag{I-15}\end{array}}$$
> as we see, by a formal change of the order of integration.

Comment: I would agree if there was another integral wrapped around the whole thing, so that the result appeared under an integral, and that integral would have to be over either $\beta$ or $\tau$. On its own, without such context, the correct answer would be the one I have given above, i.e. it vanishes for $\beta\neq\tau$ and is undefined otherwise.

Comment: In the strict sense, distributions don't exist outside of an integral. Or in other words, distributions represent linear forms and the integral is part of that form.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac: Yes, I agree, but this is always the case with Dirac impulses (or distributions in general). They make sense under an integral. So I think we can agree that what Eq. (3) of my answer means is that IF in an appropriate environment (i.e., inside an appropriate integral), the result of the integral in the OP equals a Dirac impulse with argument $\beta-\tau$.

Comment: Good, then we're on the same page!

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the Fourier Integrals book. It seems for my situation your answer is correct!

Comment: I'm just glad to see Jazz hanging around.